# Regex match valid Number

Tags: regex

This is my problem:

234 is valid
230 is not valid

For this, I've used this regex : ^[0-9]+[^0]$
but it didn't work. 
I tried to change this regex for : ^[1-9]+[^0]$

26660 it's Ok it's not valid but
2066 it's not ok because of [1-9].

Thanks!

Comment: Use `^[0-9]*[1-9]$` if you want to match any digits not ending with `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a gamble answering this, since your question isn't really all that clear.

Anyway, it helps if you rephrase the Regex in plain english.  In your case:

```
^[0-9]+[^0]$
```

Which reads as: it has to start with at least one character 0-9, as many times as possible... followed by any character other than a 0, which must be the end of the string as well.

Which almost assuredly isn't what you want.  After all, '123a' is a match (the last character isn't a 0.)  And '3' isn't a match, even though you probably want it to match.

So, if what you're looking for is 'Any number that doesn't end in a '0', then...

```
^[0-9]*[1-9]$
```

How does that translate to english?  Any number of characters 0-9 (and that includes *no* characters) followed by a character 1-9, which ends the string.

Two very useful things to do when working with Regex:

- Google 'Regex Online' - there are a number of online regex testers.
- Google 'Regex Cheat Sheet' - there are a number of quick guides on
  how to compose regex.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is right.
What language do you use?

You can try Regex online by this website.

[Online regex](https://regex101.com/r/v3LFiM/1)

And I use it to check your regex, it ran well.

Comment: Thanks Chih Sean Hsu, you're wright. I didn't pay enough attention on Online regex. It's just that when I tried so, it shows me that is valid (230) when I pressed ENTER.

Comment: @Tom: that's because most of the online-regex testers support multiline input. If you press enter a linebreak \n will be appended to the string. So the string you test against would be "230\n" which then of course would match your regular expression.